# Is there a way of creating a Serial Number based on other inputs on a MS access form?

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have some samples I need to take.

In order to create a good identifier/serial number for the samples, I want it to be a product of its characteristics.

For example, if the sample was taken from India and the temperature was 40 degrees then I would click dropdowns in the form to create those two entries and then a serial number would be spat out in the form "Ind40".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your form is bound to a table, you can create a calculated column in the table that concatenates the values from other columns into a single value.

For instance, create a new column and give it a name (for example, SerialNbr). Then for Data Type select "Calculated". An expression builder window will appear: [image]

Enter the columns you'd like to concatenate and separate them with &. Here is an example of how the expression could look:

```
Left([Country],3) & [Temperature]
```

This expression takes the first 3 chars from the Country column and combines it with the value from Temperature column to create the value in column SerialNbr. The calculated column will automatically update when values are entered into the other fields. I'd also suggest adding another value to the calculated expression to help avoid duplicates, such as date/time of submission.

Comment: One drawback to calculated fields is that they cannot be indexed so if we use one in the WHERE clause of a query we get a table scan. An alternative would be create a normal column of the appropriate type (e.g., Short Text) and then use an event-driven "Before Change" [data macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) to create the derived value and store it in the new column.